# How to route selenium webdriver to the right node in the grid?

Tags: java, android, node.js, selenium, grid

Suppose I have 2 node on the same grid: 
one is 1 instance of FF and the other one is an android device. 
In my tests I use 2 drivers: one for the FF and the other for the android. If the grid's node are not align with the order of the driver's initialization, I will get an error:

> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver
>   executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;".

So the question is how do I tell the driver to route to the right node?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DesiredCapabilities. Here is an example:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setPlatform(platform); 
// available platforms: {WINDOWS|XP|VISTA|MAC|LINUX|UNIX|ANDROID}
capabilities.setBrowserName(browser); 
// browser types: {android|chrome|firefox|htmlunit|internet explorer|iPhone|iPad|opera|safari}

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(config.get("selenium.hub")), capabilities); 
// just URL to hub and your capabilities
```

By setting platform and browser you can specify the route to node ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with routing selenium to the right node. Nodes are matched with incoming requests automatically by hub, based on desired capabilities.

The problem I can see here is explicitly related to 'webdriver.ie.driver'. You try to instantiate IE driver before this param is set. Double-check you are instantiating right driver class - you need FF and android, not IE.